# How to configuring Android Instrumentation driver

Tags: android, testing, junit, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I executed the below command for the automation suite.

```
./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.sample.easyprefs.kotlin.TestSuite -i
```

I got the results as given below:

> com.google.testing.platform.server.strategy.NonInteractiveServerStrategy
> run INFO: Constructing runner from config.
>
> com.google.testing.platform.runtime.android.driver.AndroidInstrumentationDriver
> configure INFO: Configuring Android Instrumentation driver:

```
android_instrumentation_runtime {
  instrumentation_info {
    app_package: "com.sample.easyprefs"
    test_package: "com.sample.easyprefs.test"
    test_runner_class: "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  instrumentation_args {
    args_map {
      key: "additionalTestOutputDir"
      value: "/sdcard/Android/media/com.sample.easyprefs/additional_test_output"
    }
    args_map {
      key: "class"
      value: "com.sample.easyprefs.kotlin.TestSuite"
    }
  }
}
am_instrument_timeout: 31536000
```

I tried to add this section to the Gradle but unfortunately not getting success even any references are not available in the Android testing documents, can anyone know about it? how can we **Configuring Android Instrumentation driver?**